# What word/title should I use in an email asking for updates

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, email

I would like to contact my recruiter (via email) asking for updates on my application.
What should I put in the title so it is informative, but also at the same time does not sound like I am too impatient? (I also would like to provide additional information about my accomplishments in the email)

Thanks

Comment: I think this is *seriously* Off Topic. ELU is supposed to be about interesting aspects of English usage, not writing advice for job applicants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An email title like one of the following may serve.

> Status of my application?
>   Current status of 123's application?
>   How is my application progressing?

If you like, tack on “And new accomplishments” or similar at the end; for example:

> Status of my application?  (New data enclosed)

In email titles, both brevity and specificity matter.  Leave out irrelevant or non-specific words.  Leave out articles *a* and *the*.